# Error Updating Mysql database using HTML Form and Ajax

Tags: html, ajax

I have a form Which uses a drop down box and a hidden form field to pass information to a php page, this all works except when i try to pass the information using AJAX.  If i send direct to the php page that works fine, so i know the error must be in my AJAx code, below is my HTML form and my AJAX code.

```
  <form action="" method="POST" id="update" class="update" name="update">
             <select name="status">
              <option value="Open">Open</option>
              <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
              <option value="On Hold">On Hold</option>
             </select>
         <input type="hidden" name="joborder_id" value="<?php echo "$joborder_id"; ?>">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="update" value="update"/>
   </form>




 $(document).ready(function(){
$('form.update').submit(function () {
var status = $(this).find('.status').attr('value');
var joborder_id = $(this).find('.joborder_id').attr('value');
// ...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_status.php",
        data: "status="+ status +"& joborder_id="+ joborder_id,
        success: function(){
            $('form.update').hide(function()  {$('div.success').fadeOut();});

        }
    });
return false;
});
  });
```

PHP section, this is just very basic to see if it works

```
  include ("../connect/db.php");

// CLIENT INFORMATION
$status =   $_POST['status'];
$joborder_id        = $_POST['joborder_id'];

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE joborders SET status='$status' WHERE   joborder_id='$joborder_id'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with serializeArray of the form to send information and inform of dataType json.

```
...
data: $("#form_id").serializeArray(),
dataType: 'json',
...
```

Comment: sorry how would i fit that in to the code i already have do just swap out the data: section

Comment: Please try adding a backslash to the url filename: "/update_status.php"

Answer (score 0):

Send the data as a JSON object like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.update').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_status.php",
            data: {
                status: $(this).find('.status').val(),
                oborder_id: $(this).find('.joborder_id').val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('form.update').hide(function()  {$('div.success').fadeOut();});

            }
        });
    return false;
   });
  });
```

If you want to send all fields in the form you can replace `data: { ... },` with:

```
data: $(this).serializeArray(),
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried that but i am having the same issue which is it is not updating the php page.  if i update form action to take me to the update_status.php page it works fine, but it just doesn't seem to work through the ajax process

Comment: Can you add the relevant part from `update_status.php` to your question?

Comment: OK i have added that, as you will see it is very basic, just to see if i can get it working

Comment: The code seems ok so I suggest to gather some more debug information. Check your console if you have response errors, add the error callback [see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), log success data as in my (edited) answer etc.